# php fopen relative path broken - mystery

Tags: php, relative-path, path

I know "something must have been changed" but my code seems to have broken over night for no reason.

My server directory structure is something like this:

> /
>    
> /scripts
>    
> /audit
>    
> /other_things

I have a script (let's say it's called "/scripts/MyScript.php") in the "scripts" folder which gathers data from a webpage using curl, and saves a dated copy of the webpage it reads in the "audit" folder.

To write to the audit folder, I used

> $fh = fopen("./audit/2008-09-09-183000.backup.log","w");

however that stopped working, throwing

> [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/web/website.co.uk/audit/2008-09-09-183000.backup.log on line 353

I have however fixed this by changing the path to

> "../audit/2008 etc." from "./audit/2008" (that's two full stops/periods, instead of one)

Logic dictates that something must have changed in the server configuration, but what?  It is a dedicated server which I manage. How can I avoid something like this happening again?

I've even gone through SVN for MyScript.php and all previous versions have used the single . in the path.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `dirname(__FILE__)` to get the filesystem path for the current file. Then use relative paths from there to locate your `audit` directory.

For example, within `scripts/MyScript.php`, `dirname(__FILE__)` will return `/home/web/website.co.uk/scripts`. You can reliably append `/../audit` to that.

(Note this even works in an `include`d or `require`d file—in that case it will return the directory in which the *included* file is located).

Answer (score 0):

Your CWD (current working directory) has changed it was the document root and now it's document root/scripts.

That could have happened due to the path used to access the script, for example, if you did  before http://website.co.uk/MyScript.php due to some url rewriting or whatnot and you are now accessing http://website.co.uk/scripts/MyScript.php.

I seem to recall there are other possible culprits but I can't remember them now. Did you mangle with some rewrite rules or URLs? (ie, started using PATH_INFO?)

Answer (score 0):

Is too late for this answer sure, i am a learner maybe help someone else!

```
    $dir=(__DIR__).'/'; //Path to current script location
    $path="../"; //Use any relative path to your script as you want and exists
    $file="file.txt"; //A dummy test file
    $fullpath=$dir.$path.$file; //That is the important path to store your file
    $content="This is a dummy text"; //As you read

    $draft=fopen($fullpath,"x") or die ('Something went wrong'); //"x" mean only for write if file already exists return error use any flag you need you can use any var name for "$draft" can use for example "$handle" instead
    fwrite($draft, $content); //Writes content inside file
    fclose($draft); //Close the dummy test file 

    if (file_exists($fullpath)) { //Verify is file has been created
      echo 'File created '."Ok!".'<br>'; 
    } else {
      echo 'File do not created function is '."scrubbed!".'<br>';
    };

    $data=file_get_contents($fullpath); //Verifies if content writed is ok

    if ($data==$content) {
      echo 'All content is '."Ok!".'<br>'; 
    } else {
      echo 'All content is '."scrubbed!".'<br>';
    };
```